# regular expression including date

Tags: regex, date

I'd like some help enhancing a very simple regex please.

The conditions are: string value; fixed length = 10; can include characters [0-9] only.

For this I have: ^\d{10}$

I would like to enhance this to enforce the following:

First 6 characters must be a valid date (format ddmmyy)

Help appreciated.
thanks
Paul

Comment: I don't know how to combine the above rules with the date requirement rule. So nothing.

Comment: This can be done, but the pattern will be probably > 300 chars. Also, you can't 100% check if a date is valid if you only know the last two digits of the year: should `290200` be valid or not? (I admit that is a rare corner case).

Comment: What language are you using? If it's JS or just about any other language, you can easily create a date object from a string to accurately determine if the string is actually a valid date.

Comment: I'm using asp.net regular expresion validator

Comment: big thanks to those who downvoted me. just great.

Comment: I don't understand why you were downvoted. This is a perfectly valid question. Hope our answers helped.

Answer (score 1):

One cannot truly and accurately validate a date with pure RegEx. However, if you just want a general constraint such as days cannot exceed 31 and months cannot exceed 12 then the following should work fine:

```
^(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])[0-9]{2}\d{4}$
```

The ending `\d{4}` is to ensure the remaining 4 characters are also digits as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to do this with regex only, I think you would have to break it down like this:

For the DDMM part:

- (0 + 1-9 | 1-2 + 0-9 | 3 + 0-1) + 01|03|05|07|08|10|12 or
- (0 + 1-9 | 1-2 + 0-9 | 30) + 04|06|09|11 or
- (0 + 1-9 | 1-2 + 0-9) + 02

for the YY part:

- 0-9 + 0-9

Then just put that together into one ridiculously long regex pattern.

Hope that makes sense. Note that this doesn't completely work, as it will allow invalid dates like 2/29/01 (February 29 on non-leap years).

Like @tenub said, you can't really accurately validate a date using regex alone.